# Cumulocity measurement representation

Tags: cumulocity

I create measurements at reception of an event, I can get them using the API, but they are not represented graphically in the Device Management interface. I there a specific format they would have to respect to be representable automatically? If so, is there a place I can find all the formats supported by Cumulocity? I infered the c8y_TemperatureMeasurement from the examples in the doc but I didn't find an exhaustive list of the native formats.

Here are examples of the measurements I have at the moment:

```
{
  "time": "2016-06-29T12:10:02.000+02:00",
  "id": "27006",
  "self": "https://<tenant-id>/measurement/measurements/27006",
  "source": {
    "id": "26932",
    "self": "https://<tenant-id>/inventory/managedObjects/26932"
  },
  "type": "c8y_BatteryMeasurement",
  "c8y_BatteryMeasurement": {
    "unit": "V",
    "value": 80
  }
},
{
  "time": "2016-06-29T10:15:22.000+02:00",
  "id": "27010",
  "self": "https://<tenant-id>/measurement/measurements/27010",
  "source": {
    "id": "26932",
    "self": "https://<tenant-id>/inventory/managedObjects/26932"
  },
  "type": "c8y_TemperatureMeasurement",
  "c8y_TemperatureMeasurement": {
    "T": {
      "unit": "C",
      "value": 24
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The measurements have to be sent to Cumulocity in the following format:

    {
        "fragment": {
            "series": {
                "unit": "x",
                "value": y
            }
        }
    }

so the second one you posted should be visible as a Datapoint. Can you see those measurements in the ```Cockpit``` application?

Comment: Thank you I does indeed, I just didn't set the time window right. Thanks for the format.

Comment: btw If you put that as an answer, then I can accept it!

Comment: Thanks, put it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The measurements have to be sent to Cumulocity in the following format:

```
{
    "fragment": {
        "series": {
            "unit": "x",
            "value": y
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also give us the JSON format for Event and Alerts